# ROS Answers SE migration: ROSCON 2014

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any proposed dates, venues or location for this year ?

I have found it useful to ask for sponsors grants and contributions 6-12 months before an event.

In addition, it takes some planning for people to attend )

Cheers Everyone

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/116741/roscon-2014/) by [uaflyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/10681/uaflyer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2014-01-10

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lanyusea](https://answers.ros.org/users/10266/lanyusea/) on 2014-01-12**:
it will be in HongKong.
a professor in my university is the ROSCON 2014 cooperator, I heard him talking about this last month.  <--- treat my words just like a rumor please

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2014-01-16**:
This kind of question (and following discussion) would probably be best suited for the ROS users mailing list?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-01-16**:
Random guess: If it's rumored to be in Hong Kong it might be attached to ICRA.

**Comment by [uaflyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/10681/uaflyer/) on 2014-01-16**:
I am on far too many mailing lists and not on this ros one so far..
One must be careful about rules in an Opens Source effort, it can cause big adoption problems>
Cloudstack and Citirx made this mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: ROSKong 2014 has been announced for June 6th in Hong Kong in conjunction with ICRA.  Full information is available at https://events.osrfoundation.org/ros-kong-2014/

ROSCon 2014 is expected to take place in October near IROS in Chicago.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uaflyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/10681/uaflyer/) on 2014-01-16**:
any chance of intermediary events, besides something each year ?  I am sure they happen )
I will follow the blog and here, I get thousands of email a week across several emails

btw- some rumor can be effective in promoting the org.  It can be constructive.  it is what I learned at Omidyar

**Comment by [uaflyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/10681/uaflyer/) on 2014-02-05**:
I never got an answer to email asking if ROS needs sponsorship from SoftLayer or other resources

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-02-05**:
@uaflyer I haven't seen your email. Please contact me directly about sponsorship. My email is listed at http://wiki.ros.org/TullyFoote on the wiki

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that folks are already used to a May timeframe for ROSCon and it also seems that it won't be happening then... so I suggest we organize an unofficial one. I'm in Los Angeles and I'd be happy to donate $1000 if needed to get it off the ground. Anyone else out there who'd like to make this happen? Please get in touch.

---

Originally posted by [robofred](https://answers.ros.org/users/14426/robofred/) with karma: 11 on 2014-04-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-04-05**:
ROSCon will be happening in October with IROS. And ROSKong will be in June with ICRA.  If you'd like to organize an event feel free. Please do not use ROSCon as the name to avoid conflicts. See http://wiki.ros.org/Events for other regional meetups already ongoing.